# Not able to center button quite right

Tags: css, button, centering, margins

I'm trying to center a button in an ASP.NET container. I've looked at quite a few answers here and on other sites. I found one post that says to use

```
<center></center>
```

Tags and that's the only suggestion that works somewhat so far. It does center the button mostly, but it is still just a little bit off to one side. What I would like to do is instead of using a suggestion that kind of works like the center tag above I would like to be able to set the margins for the button. Will someone please help me with this? I know it's probably a simple answer but I'm very new to ASP.NET.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code I am using:

```
<asp:Button id="uxUploadExcel" runat="server" Text="Pull Student Data"/>
```

Comment: The `<center>` tag is obsolete and should not be used anymore.  Please edit your question to include your current code.  As it is, you have not provided sufficient context for anyone to assist beyond guessing.  Review [ask].

Comment: All the more reason to use something better.

Comment: I added my code above, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The preferred alternative is to use CSS styling, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center for alternatives

Comment: The <center> cannot hold,  it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use CSS here and apply it on the parent container. You can also set margins on the button via CSS.

```css
.parentContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

#uxUploadExcel {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentContainer">
  <button id="uxUploadExcel" runat="server">Pull Student Data</button>
</div>
```

Note: I wrote out a plain html button here but an ASP.NET button can be used in place of it.